# Assigning Entity Keys in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a very precise gap of knowledge of the assignement of the entity keys in entity framework.

When you set a variable to become the entity key of an entity, if you are doing code first or model first it sets the column as identity but what if I assign the entity key to 0 in the default constructor of my model first class, what does EF do?

Will EF notice that it was an auto assignement and ignore the default value I set in the constructor?

Or should I never assign an entity key other than when im retrieving data?

Answer (score 1):

So far I have yet to see the first scenario where there is absolutely no alternative for setting an `EntityKey` object. But I assume you're not referring to that but to setting a key *value*.

Setting a primary key value is hardly ever necessary when the key is generated by the database (identity column). If you want EF to insert an entity you don't set the primary key, but you set its [`EntityState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entitystate.aspx) to `Added` (either directly or indirectly).

I can think of one scenario where setting primary key values is useful: using [stub entities](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/19/tip-26-how-to-avoid-database-queries-using-stub-entities.aspx). For example, suppose you know that object A with id value 3 must be deleted, but object A has not been fetched from the database. So there is no object which state can be changed to `Deleted`. In that case you can prevent a roundtrip to the database by creating a stub entity A that only has its Id value filled, attach it to a context as `Deleted` and save changes.